# Getting a value from a particular state before component renders using react/redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react/redux with a nodejs(express)/mongodb back-end incase that helps.

What I want to happen here is that if a user tries to go to edit a post that does not belong to them I want them to be re routed immediately and never see that page.

For example. User "A" goes to route `localhost:8080/posts/post_id/edit`, but that post belongs to user "B". I want User A to immediately get re routed back to that post or `localhost:8080/posts/post_id`.

In my code I can get the user through a action called getUser() which sends an axios.get request to the back-end to get the current user who is logged in. I am using JWT token. Not sure if this is information needed or not.

Here is the code to show you what I am trying to do.

```
import React , { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as actions from '../../actions/posts_actions';
import * as actionsIndex from '../../actions/index';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

class EditPost extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    if(this.props.auth) {
      console.log(this.props.auth); // -> returns true
      this.props.getUser(); // -> this fires off
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    this.props.getOnePost(id);
    if(this.props.auth){
      if(this.props.user._id !== this.props.post.author.id){
        this.props.history.push(`/posts/${id}`);
      }
    }
  }

  renderField(field) {
    const { meta: {touched, error} } = field;
    const className = `form-group ${touched && error ? 'has-danger' : ''}`;

    return (
      <div className={className}>
        <label><strong>{field.label}:</strong></label>
        <input
          className="form-control"
          type={field.type}
          {...field.input}
        />
        <div className="text-help">
          { touched ? error : ''}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  onSubmit(values) {
    const {id} = this.props.match.params;

    this.props.updatePost(values, id, () => {
      this.props.history.push(`/posts/${id}`);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    const {id} = this.props.match.params;
    console.log(this.props.user); // -> shows me the user after three nulls
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
        <Field
          label="Title"
          name="title"
          type="text"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <Field
          label="Content"
          name="content"
          type="text"
          component={this.renderField}
        />
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        <Link to={`/posts/${id}`} className="btn btn-danger">Cancel</Link>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

function validate(values) {
  const errors = {};

  if(!values.title) {
    errors.title = "Enter a title!";
  }
  if(!values.content) {
    errors.content = "Enter some content please!";
  }

  return errors;
}

function mapStateToProps({ posts, auth, user }, ownProps) {
  return {
    initialValues: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
    post: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
    auth: auth.authenticated,
    user: user
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({...actions, ...actionsIndex}, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'editform'
})(EditPost));
```

Here are the console.log statements:

[image]

Here is an edit of the index.js page , is there some way I could update the user state here?:

```
"use strict"
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from './reducers/index';
import App from './components/app';
import '../style/style.css';

import Home from './components/pages/home';
import Header from './components/header';
import Footer from './components/footer';
import RequireAuth from './components/auth/require_auth';
import RequireUnAuth from './components/auth/require_unauth';

import Signin from './components/auth/signin';
import Signup from './components/auth/signup';
import Signout from './components/auth/signout';

import Posts from './components/pages/posts';

import {AUTH_USER} from './actions/types';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

if(token) {
  store.dispatch({ type: AUTH_USER });
}

const Routes = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
)

ReactDOM.render(Routes, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `this.props.getUser()` is an async (thunk-ed) action creator, you're not guaranteed to have the result of that available by the time you reach `componentDidMount`

Add a null check for `this.props.user` in `componentDidMount` before you attempt to access fields on it.

Something you could do is move

```
if(this.props.user._id !== this.props.post.author.id){
  this.props.history.push(`/posts/${id}`);
}
```

into `componentWillReceiveProps`

```
componentWillReceiveProps ({ user: nextUser }) {
    const { history, match, user: currentUser, post } = this.props
    const { id } = match.params

    /* if you didn't previously have currentUser (i.e. after first load) - !currentUser
     * or the user has changed - nextUser !== currentUser*/
    if (!currentUser || nextUser !== currentUser) { // probably shouldn't use === here
      /* the component might update before `this.props.getUser()` "returns", so make sure this is the
       * update we are looking for by ensuring that we have nextUser -  nextUser &&
       * then get the id (nextUser._id), and run the check (!== post.author.id)*/
      if (nextUser && (nextUser._id !== post.author.id)) {
        history.push(`/posts/${id}`)
      }
    }
  }
```

[Here's a little light Friday reading](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) on `componentWillReceiveProps` - might clear some things up.

A couple things regarding your edit:

1. An [HoC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) might be a good idea if you have a lot of components that rely on `user`

`AuthComponent` HoC concept

```
class AuthComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.props.user) {
      this.props.getUser()
    }
  }

  render() {
    // you could inject `user` into children here, but I would suggest that you 
    // instead store the result of `getUser` into a store like `redux` or `flux` and fetch from that in child components
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

Obviously you'll need to use `connect` and grab `user` out of state for this component. You would use it like

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <AuthComponent>
        <WrappedComponent/> // <- this is what's rendered
      </AuthComponent>
    )
  }
}
```

you're using `react-router`, though, so a better solution would be to incorporate it into your routing

```
<Route path="" component={AuthComponent}>
  <Route path="some-path" component={WrappedComponent}/>
</Route>
```

2. like I said in the comment, cache and return `user` from your store... although it looks like you're already doing this
3. don't assume that you'll always have access to `user` - make sure you're null checking it

Comment: This does work however I dont really get the logic on the last if statement. Could you maybe explain it a little bit?

Comment: yeah sorry - it was a little messy - I've added some comments.

Comment: simplified it a little bit - `nextUser` should always have either the current or new user so you don't have to do the checks I was doing.

Comment: Thank you! I added an edit and was wondering if there was a way to fire off the getUser action in the index.js page using store.dispatch?

Comment: Thank you so much! You know very much about react and how to explain it! Is there a way we can move this into a chat, I got the HOC to work, but if I hit refresh once on the page I want the user turns into null. I think this is because react state gets wiped with a hard refresh?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148080/discussion-between-tyler-sebastian-and-taylor-austin).

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are using in your componentWillMount does not belong here.

```
this.props.getUser();
```

You better create an action [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) creator which deals with promise + async actions and only then return the result through the state/dispatch mechanism to be later used in componentDidMount lifecycle hook.

Redux thunk example to call API, please take a look at [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) docs:

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument(api))
)

// later
function fetchUser(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState, api) => {
    // you can use api here
  }
}
To pass multiple things, just wrap them in a single object and use destructuring:

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ api, whatever }))
)

// later
function fetchUser(id) {
  return (dispatch, getState, { api, whatever }) => {
    // you can use api and something else here here
  }
}
```

Comment: this.props.getUser is an action create that uses axios and sends a request to the backend getting the user and then through the reducer sets that user state to that user.

Comment: as I said classic for redux thunk

Comment: So where do I call the action then?

Comment: where it is is fine (`componentDidMount` would be better, though), it's that you're expecting it to have completed and the store to update by the time you get to `componentDidMount`

Comment: I added my index.js page where I create the store, is there a way to call the action there? Also sorry I am pretty new to react/redux.